# Pasaje de Datos de array mediante onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html

Buenas tardes necesio ayuda con un tema. Traigo los datos desde una api con *curl* en php los cual los guardo en un array y eso anda perfecto, muestro los datos en un table y en ese table tengo un `input button` el cual necesito que, al hacer click, me mande la posición del array seleccionado a `pedido.php`, el cual recibe el array y lo muestra en una tabla. Les dejo un poco de código a ver si me pueden dar una mano. Un Saludo

**Tabla**

```
<td>
  <img  src="<?php echo $valor['foto'] ; $i++ ;?>" border='0' width='50' height='50' onmouseover="this.width=500;this.height=500" onmouseout="this.width=50;this.height=50">
</td>
<td><?php echo $valor['descripcion']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $valor['familia'] ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $valor['codigo'] ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $valor['descripcionadicional']; ?></td>
<td><?php if ($valor['precio1'] <= 0) echo "Sin disponibilidad"; else echo $valor['precio1']; ?></td>
```

**Botón**

```
<input 
  type="button" 
  class="button" method="POST"
  value="Agregar a pedido" 
  name="Agregar"  
  id ="Agregar" 
  title="Agregar" 
  onclick="my()"
/>
```

Comment: Matías, bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ver la [sección de ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para entender cómo funciona el sitio y le saques más provecho.

Comment: *"me mande la posición del array seleccionado"*. Supongo que cada fila de la tabla tiene un checkbox, ¿cierto?. ¿Deseas hacerlo por AJAX o por petición normal? ¿Podrías poner el contenido de la función `my`?

Comment: Te recomiendo que adjuntes el codigo de tu funcion _my()_, para ayudarte mas facilmente

Comment: Estoy intentando hacerlo por ajax, cada fila de la tabla tiene un input button pero creo que no me funciona correctamente, te dejo el codigo de la funcion my

<script>
     var array = new array();
     function my(array){
   var url = 'pedido.php';
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: url,
     data: {array},
     success:function(array){
        console.log("tu varible de sesion tiene el valor de "+ array);
     }
   });
}   
     </script>

Comment: Yo estoy pasando datos de una tabla no de un contenedor, no se si en el data del ajax puedo poner <?php $valor ['descripcion'] ?> para que tome ese valor

Answer (score 0):

Para comenzar, el valor de la posición del array deberías imprimirlo junto a la tabla.

EDITO: Cambio parte del codigo al tener mas info.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <img
            src="<?php echo $valor['foto'] ; $i++ ;?>"
            border='0' width='50' height='50'
            onmouseover="this.width=500;this.height=500"
            onmouseout="this.width=50;this.height=50"
        />
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $valor['descripcion']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $valor['familia'] ;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $valor['codigo'] ;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $valor['descripcionadicional']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <?php
            if ($valor['precio1'] <= 0)
                echo "Sin disponibilidad";
            else
                echo $valor['precio1'];
        ?>
    </td>
    <td><button data-pos="<?php echo $posicion_en_array;?>">ENVIAR</button></td>
</tr>
```

Luego, en el `onclick` quedaría algo así.

```
$("td > button").on("click",function(){
     var pos = $(this).attr("data-pos");
     $.post("tu-pagina.php",{"posicion":pos},function(){
             //-- Hacer algo cuando termine el envio
     })
})
```

En la otra página recibes la información:

```
$pos_array = $_REQUEST["posicion"]; //-- Posicion del array. Previamente a esta linea tenes que tener cargado el array.
```

Comment: Te hago una consulta, despues como lo recibiria en la otra pagina a lo que estoy mandando?